# Is it possible to define an interceptor on an interface in Quarkus?

Tags: java, cdi, quarkus, interceptor

In my working on an application using Quarkus and I want to intercept a method of an interface. I tried the following but its not working:

1. First of all I define an annotation:

```
@Target({ TYPE, METHOD })
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Documented
@InterceptorBinding
public @interface EnableLogging {
}
```

2. Define the interceptor and annotating it with `EnableLogging`:

```
@Priority(10)
@Interceptor
@EnableLogging
public class LogInterceptor {

    @AroundInvoke
    public Object aroundInvoke(InvocationContext context) throws Exception {
        //do logging
        return context.proceed();
    }
}
```

3. Create an interface and its implementation which I want to intercept. **My main goal is that I want to annotate the interface not its implementation**. Something like bellow:

```
@EnableLogging
public interface DummyService {

    void successfulCall();
}
```

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class DummyServiceImpl implement DummyClient  {

    void successfulCall(){
         // do something
    }
}
```

however, with above implementation, I did not catch `aroundInvoke` method.

**UPDATE:**

Based on @Ladicek answer, I take this approach for abstract class and it totally worked!

```
@EnableLogging
public abstract class DummyService {

    public abstract void successfulCall();
}
```

Could someone help me, please?

Comment: This is not possible. In CDI, annotations on methods are never inherited, just like in the Java language itself. This includes annotations on methods of superclasses and superinterfaces, and applies to all cases where annotations on methods are considered by CDI, including interceptors.

Comment: @Ladicek that sounds like a proper answer instead of a comment :)

Comment: @Ladicek thanks for your reply, but this approach correctly worked for abstract class. I update my question.

Comment: My bad, I thought you're annotating the _method_. Still, the essence of my answer holds. The CDI rules for annotation inheritance [mostly] follow the Java language rules for annotation inheritance. That is: annotations are inherited 1. only on a class declaration (nowhere else), 2. only from superclasses (not from superinterfaces). So your approach with an `abstract` class works, because the annotation is present on a superclass. (We actually intentionally have a bug in Quarkus / ArC where we consider an annotation inherited even if it isn't `@Inherited`, but we'll fix that one day.)

Comment: @Ladicek does this somewhow related to the issued reported in https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/23956 ?!

Comment: That seems unlikely, JAX-RS implementations do their own discovery and have different annotation inheritance rules than CDI.